# UIImagePickerController not asking for permissions on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-permissions

I have an iOS app where I present an image picker the

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.picker];
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

The app however doesn't ask for permissions at all, it just displays the error message "This app does not have access to your photos or videos".

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Access has been denied earlier?

Comment: Nope, I deleted the app, reseted the Privacy settings and the issue persists.

Comment: what version of iOS?

Comment: It seems to be iOS 9 only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was the the Bundle Display Name wasn't set in the Info.plist

Comment: To be on safer side ... we can add **Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description** in **info.plist**

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 9, UIPopoverController is deprecated and why don't you use presentViewController instead.

Comment: I tried this too: https://gist.github.com/iliketosneeze/e7b012f260953db5667c
but I get the same issue

Comment: You can try to use Full Screen style, not popover, I am not sure why you are going to use popover.

Comment: If I use full screen I just get a black screen. The code only doesn't seem to work on iPads on iOS 9. On other devices and versions it works.

Comment: Try to check [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] and check what the result value is,  Also try to add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key in info.plist

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary seems to be deprecated too, I even get an undeclared identifier error. I do have NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription already in the info.plist.